# Why do you have to specify a type for pointers?

Tags: c++

Why do you have to set a type for pointers? Aren’t they just a placeholder for addresses and all those addresses? Therefore, won't all pointers no matter what type specified occupy an equal size of memory?

Comment: How else would the compiler (and more importantly the programmers reading the code) know what the pointer is actually pointing to?

Comment: Also, you seem to be misunderstanding the pointers and their size. While there are (old) platforms where there could be different kind of pointers and possibly taking up different amount of space. These days a pointer is basically just an unsigned 32 or 64 bit integer whose value is the address it is pointing to, so indeed the pointers *themselves* do "occupy an equal size of memory".

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You don't have to specify a type for pointers.  You can use `void*` everywhere, which would force you to insert an explicit type cast every single time you read something from the address pointed by the pointer, or write something to that address, or simply increment/decrement or otherwise manipulate the value of the pointer.

But people decided a long time ago that they were tired of this way of programming, and preferred typed pointers that

- do not require casts
- do not require always having to know the size of the pointed type (which is an issue that gets even more complicated when proper memory alignment has to be taken into consideration)
- prevent you from accidentally accessing the wrong data type or advancing the pointer by the wrong number of bytes.

And yes, indeed, all data pointers, no matter what their type, occupy the same amount of memory, which is usually 4 bytes on 32-bit systems, and 8 bytes on 64-bit systems.  The type of a data pointer has nothing to do with the amount of memory occupied by the pointer, and that's because no type information is stored with the pointer; the pointer type is only useful to humans and to the compiler, not to the machine.

Comment: Thanks, it makes more sense now. However, I got a question for you: If i declared this pointer `void* pointer`, would its type be `void*` or just `void`?

Comment: And are you even specifying the type **of** the pointer? Or are you specifying what type it will point to? If you are not specifying the type **of** the pointer, why can you then say that the type of the pointer is a specific type?

Comment: In the case of `void* pointer`, the type of the variable is `void*`, because it is a pointer, and the type it points to is `void`. (That's the type of `*pointer`.)  So, when we say we specify the type of the pointer, we take the "pointing" into account.  When we say "an int pointer" or "a pointer to int" we mean "a variable of type `int*`", that is, a pointer which points to type `int`.

Comment: Not entirely correct, member function pointers is typically larger than other pointers

Comment: @PasserBy the only situations that I know of where code pointer size *can* be different than data pointer size is *some memory models* of 16-bit intel, and I think that in 2017 that's a trifling exception to the rule, hardly worth the effort of mentioning.

Comment: No, member function pointers are different beasts, they are not plain code pointers. [Live](https://godbolt.org/g/6KEif8). And to be pedant, the standard places no requirements on pointer sizes

Comment: @PasserBy meh, ok.

Comment: @MikeMakis and there are still platforms where pointers are more complex than lineae address.. it's either very small scale ones (e.g. something in your digital camera or a RC drone or an industrial  production line) or rather big ones (data crunching mainframes). They aren't gone, no matter was PC and tablet people wish to say.

Comment: @PasserBy I forgot to mention that I fixed this a long time ago, thank you for your suggestion.

Comment: @Swift-FridayPie I forgot to mention that I fixed this a long time ago, thank you for your suggestion.

Comment: If you guys believe that the answer needs any further clarification in order to not be wrong with respect to the difference between code pointers and data pointers, please let me know.

Comment: This doesn't explain why a type declaration is needed. The compiler can always infer that `foo*` is a different type from `bar*` because it has a different name, hence obtaining type safety. Why did the C++ language designers deem it necessary to force users to tell the compiler whether `foo` is a class or a function before being able to declare a `foo*`? Unless it's to allow users to declare a function that takes a "pointer to any class" or "pointer to any function"?

Comment: I just thought of a reason: the C++ Standard says that pointer-to-class can be different size from pointer-to-function. So to know how big a pointer is, the compiler needs to know if the pointer points to a class or a function.

Comment: @1f604 yes, this has already been brought to my attention, and that's why back in 2017 I amended my answer to talk about _data pointers_ instead of pointers in general.

Answer (score 4):

Different types take up different amounts of memory. So when advancing a pointer (e.g. in an array), we need to take the type's size into account.
For example, because a char takes up only one byte, going to the next element means adding 0x01 to the address. But because a int takes up 4 bytes (on many architectures), getting to the next element requires adding 0x04 to the address stored in the pointer.
Now, we could have a single pointer type which simply describes an address without type information (in fact, this is what void* is for), but then every time we wanted to increment or decrement it, we'd need to give the type's size as well.

Here's some real C code which demonstrates the pains you'd go through:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
typedef void* pointer;
int main(void) {
    pointer numbers = calloc(10, sizeof(int));
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        *(int*)(numbers + i * sizeof(int)) = i;
        /* this could have been simply "numbers[i] = i;" */
    /* ... */
    return 0;
}
```

Three important things to notice here:

- We have to multiply the index by sizeof(int) every time; adding
  simply i will not do: the first iteration would correctly access the
  first 4-byte integer, but the second iteration would look for the
  integer which starts with the second byte of the first integer, the
  third would start with the third byte of the first integer, and so
  on. It's very unlikely that this is desirable!
- The compiler needs to know how much information it can store in a
  pointer when assigning to the address it points to. For example, if
  you try to store a number greater than 2^8 in a char, the compiler
  should know to truncate the number and not overwrite the next few
  bytes of memory, which might extend into the next page (causing a
  segmentation fault) or, worse, be used to store other data in your
  program, resulting in a subtle bug.
- Speaking of width, we know in our program above that numbers stores
  ints -- what if we didn't? What if, for example, we tried to store an
  int in the address pointed to an array of a larger data type (on some
  architectures), like a long? Then our generic functions would end up
  having to compare the widths of both types, probably using the
  minimum of the two, and then if the type being stored is smaller than
  its container you start having to worry about endianness to make sure
  you align the value being stored with the correct end of the
  container.

Answer (score 0):

If you want evaluate pointed element value with pointer then you have to specify type of pointed element on declaration pointer. Because the compiler does not know the precise number of bytes to which the pointer refers. Machine has to compute particular bounded memory to evaluate the value.